# make other accordions collapse when clicking on <tr>

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using this accordion example here: http://www.bootply.com/fdTMNTiLis

All works fine but when i click on a table row I would like to make all other table rows collapse. Currently I have to manually click on each table row to collapse them.